# Can a single route in MVC be used to match all these urls?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name:="Archives",
      url:="posts/archives/{year}/{month}",
      defaults:=New With {.controller = "Posts", .action = "Archives", .year =
      UrlParameter.Optional, .month = UrlParameter.Optional})
```

That works so I get something like `http://example.com/posts/archives/2014/12`

But I also want to handle urls like

- `http://example.com/posts/archives/2014/`,
- `http://example.com/posts/archives/2014/12/page/3`, -
- `http://example.com/posts/archives/2014/page/3`

I tried adding route below:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
       name:="ArchivesWithPaging",
       url:="posts/archives/{year}/{month}/page/{page}",
       defaults:=New With {.controller = "Posts", .action = "Archives", .year =
       UrlParameter.Optional, .month = UrlParameter.Optional,
      .page = UrlParameter.Optional})
```

But then causes `http://example.com/posts/archives/2014/12`   to become `http://example.com/posts/archives/2012/12/page`

So is there a single route to catch all of these or do I need multiple routes?

Alternatively, if a single route is not possible, what routes would help me match those cases correctly?

Comment: You already know what routes you need because you just posted them... almost.  In your second route, the year, month and page would not be optional.

Comment: So then do i need to implement a custom route constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your exact question: Yes, you can use a single route to match all of these URLs. You can [implement RouteBase in a custom class](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=970) and handle exactly the routes you want to and return null for any URLs that you don't want to handle in that route.

However, you don't need to go to such an extreme for this simple scenario. To handle all of the cases for this scenario, you actually need 3 routes - one for the standard URL, one for the standard URL with paging and one for the URL without the month with paging.

You do need to ensure they are listed in the correct order, though, or they will not function as expected. Routes should generally be listed in order from most specific to least specific, paying attention first to the values on the left across to the values on the right.

For your most specific routes, I don't see much point in making anything optional except for the month. Using UrlParameter.Optional is equivalent to using empty string, which will be problematic if your controller is expecting these to be integers. You did not specify you wanted strings, so I am assuming Integers in this example:

```
Public Class PostsController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Function Archives(year As Integer, month As Integer, page As Integer) As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function

End Class
```

And here are the routes listed in order from most specific to least specific:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name:="ArchivesYearWithPaging", _
    url:="posts/archives/{year}/page/{page}", _
    defaults:=New With {.controller = "Posts", .action = "Archives", .month = 0})

routes.MapRoute(
    name:="ArchivesWithPaging", _
    url:="posts/archives/{year}/{month}/page/{page}", _
    defaults:=New With {.controller = "Posts", .action = "Archives"})

routes.MapRoute(
    name:="Archives", _
    url:="posts/archives/{year}/{month}", _
    defaults:=New With {.controller = "Posts", .action = "Archives", .page = 1, .month = 0})
```

**Explanation:**

The first route is to handle `http://example.com/posts/archives/2014/page/3`. It passes 0 as a default month to the Archives controller action method, so it is easy for you to identify when the URL doesn't specify a month.

The second route is to handle `http://example.com/posts/archives/2014/12/page/3`. If you don't use constraints (and there is really no reason you have to here), it must follow the first route because the month parameter could inadvertently match the `/page/` segment.

The third route will handle `http://example.com/posts/archives/2014/12` and `http://example.com/posts/archives/2014` because the month is optional. It also defaults the page number to 1 and month to 0 if not provided.